# How does the d3.scaleBand work?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

How can I make the line `var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);` from [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8952219) work in d3 v4 using [d3.scaleBand](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#scaleBand)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

in D3 4.x, *ordinal*.rangeRoundBands has been replaced with *band*.rangeRound (thus, there is no more `rangeRoundBands`). Besides that...

> The new *band*.padding, *band*.paddingInner and *band*.paddingOuter methods replace the optional arguments to ordinal.rangeBands.

So, that `0.05` goes to `paddingInner`. This is how the line looks in D3 v4.x:

```
d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .paddingInner(0.05);
```

I have rewritten the code in your example, updated to D3 v4.x: https://plnkr.co/edit/HQz1BL9SECFIsQ5bG8qb?p=preview

Necessary changes:

- `var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m");`
- `var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).paddingInner(0.05);`
- `var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);`
- `var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m"));`
- `var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(10);`
- for the bars: `.attr("width", x.bandwidth())`